# Path for bash in Android termux

Tags: termux

Regular paths for bash do not work in termux app. 
I tried: 
/usr/bin/bash 
and 
/bin/bash 
Also 'whereis' command gives the following output: 
$ whereis bash bash: 
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/bash 
But this path also is not correct. So, I have to run every bash script with the word 'bash' before it. And cannot run bash scripts without it.

Comment: `/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/bash` is the **only** correct path.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: As in regular linux, I want to pass: /bin/bash  or  /usr/bin/bash  in order to run scripts.  But not to write 'bash' before every script name.

Comment: Just as @DanHulme, I don't understand where the problem is. With `#!/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/bash` as the script's first line, it's then possible to execute the script by just `/path/to/the/script.sh`.

Comment: $ ls
myscript.sh
$ cat my*
#!/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/bash
read -p ' enter what to echo ' inputs
echo "u have inputed $inputs"

$ myscript.sh
myscript.sh: command not found

Comment: Command not found...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `myscript.sh` is not in your `$PATH`, you need to run it by its path, not its basename. Assuming you're in the same directory as the script, run

```
./myscript.sh
```

Note the leading `./`

Comment: Hey ♦, I could've appreciated had you left the chance for me... It's the 3rd time the same answer is posted.

Comment: @iBug You certainly deserve the credit for digging into the problem. I looked and Josef's comment made it obvious what his mistake was. I was going to comment under your answer to suggest this but realised I was really writing an answer.

Comment: Ah sí. I see the difference now.

Answer (score 3):

In September 2017 the maintainer of Termux released a package `termux-exec`, which wraps up `execve(2)` so that files that has a shebang line like `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/usr/bin/env` will run correctly in Termux. Just run

```
pkg install termux-exec
```

and restart Termux (or open a new session). You'll now be able to run `#!/bin/sh` scripts.

The previous solution was as following:

> Termux provides a handy utility
>
> ```
> termux-fix-shebang
> ```
>
> Whose description reads:
>
> > Rewrite shebangs in specified files for running under Termux,
> >     which is done by rewriting `#!*/bin/binary` to `#!$PREFIX/bin/binary`.
>
> Just apply it to the scripts you wish to run. It does what its name suggests: fix the shebang line `#!/xxx` of your script files. It can **also** fix other scripts like Perl or Python.

Also note that [by default your working directory is not in `$PATH`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/254711/211239), so you cannot directly type `myscript.sh`, but instead

```
./myscript.sh
^~
```

... or explicitly specify an interpreter shell (in which case you don't need the directory prefix):

```
bash myscript.sh
^~~~
```

Comment: Still. $myscript.sh
myscript.sh: command not found

Comment: @JosefKlimuk Would you please type `./myscript.sh`?

Comment: It was answered already by Dan Hulme on 1 Nov.

Comment: It looks like `termux-fix-shebang` is obsolete, since `termux-exec` is a better solution? If so, upvote @s-d-rausty's answer.

Comment: @CarlWalsh I'm aware of it and upvoted already.

Answer (score 3):

Install `termux-exec`.  It's a new utility that should resolve your $PATH issue.  Termux-exec allows you to execute scripts with shebangs for traditional Unix file structures.  See https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Termux-exec for more information.